# FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deployment

I am trying to deploy my model. I am encountering the following problem:

*FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram://a603e930-4fda-4105-8554-7af5e5fc02f5/variables/variables
You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'*

This happened when I stored an NLP model in a pickle. I have seen that it does not work so I then tried to save the model as `.h5` The problem still persists and shows me the above error.

Comment: Are you using some multithreading/pooling of sorts? Did you try setting the experimental_io_device option as suggested?